# Java how to "dynamically" center a string given another string?

Tags: java, format

Say we are given:

```
String line = "************************************";
```

How can I format a string so that it is always printed in the center of String line, e.g:

```
************************************
              Testing

************************************
           More Testing

************************************
   Format sentence in center here
```

I tried using StringUtils.leftPad and StringUtils.center but it ends up looking like:

```
StringUtils.center("SouthEast Hospital Branch", 32, "")
StringUtils.center("Testing", 32, "")
```

Printed results:

```
************************************
 SouthEast Hospital Branch  
            Testing
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String#repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) method to multiply text.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String line = "----------------------------------------------------------";
    
    System.out.println(line);
    printCenter("SouthEast Hospital Branch",line.length());
    System.out.println(line);
    
    printCenter("Testing", line.length());
    System.out.println(line);
}

public static void printCenter(String data, int length) {
    int padding = (length - data.length())/2;
    System.out.println(" ".repeat(padding) + data );
}
```

Output:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
                 SouthEast Hospital Branch
----------------------------------------------------------
                          Testing
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than the `String#repeat` method in the other answer, you can also pad the given String using a `for` loop.

Here is one such method:

```
private static String padString(String str, int span) {

    StringBuilder finalString = new StringBuilder();

    int spacesToAdd = (span - str.length()) / 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < spacesToAdd; i++) {
        finalString.append(" ");
    }
    finalString.append(str);
    return finalString.toString();
}
```

Whichever method you use, the important part here is the calculation of the spaces needed.

```
String separator = "--------------------------------";

System.out.println(separator);
System.out.println(padString("This is centered.", separator.length()));
System.out.println(padString("So is this!", separator.length()));
```

And here's the output:

```
--------------------------------
        This is centered.
           So is this!
```